# variable not set in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

In ngOnInit, when I do:

`console.log(this.tournament.slug);`

I get this.tournament is null

this variable comes from a parent view:

```
@Input() tournament: Tournament;
```

tournament is the result of a query, so it will take some time to get the value, so the ngOnInit is not working.

How should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Check in after view init

Comment: Check in ngAfterViewInit life cycle

Comment: No, this is incorrect, as the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook is mostly used to check for specific rendered elements, and not to be used for incoming asynchronous inputs.
See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Answer (score 4):

If it isn't set right away, maby you could use a setter on the input to react to when the parent component tries to set it?

```
    @Input()
    set tournament(val) {
        this._tournament = val;
        console.log(this._tournament.slug);
    }
```

Comment: webstorm gives : Function 'tournament' recurses infinitely, and can only end by throwing an exception

Comment: Could you post a plunkr of your case?

Comment: rename the variable tournament, it's most likely because the "this.tournament" clashes with the function with the same name. Edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hook from Angular in these cases.

Something like this :

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if(this.tournament) {
    console.log(this.tournament.slug);
  }
}
```

This is a basic implementation of the `ngOnChanges()` hook, so go to the official documentation if you have to manage a complex case (such as several inputs coming asynchronously, and being updated repeteadly, and you need to control each input separately).

Check out this link in that case : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

---

**EDIT** : As I saw in this video, and it seems really accurate, the `ngOnChanges()` hook is preferred when dealing with several `@Input()` while the setter option is preferred when dealing with one `@Input()` property.
https://youtu.be/BYwfrSlJFfY?t=711